# odoo send message to user from code (notification)

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I'm trying to make a module that will check Skype and inform users about new messages. I ran into the problem of sending a message to a user by his id in odoo, do I need to inherit somewhere from the message module, or do I need to somehow manage the code so that the messages are sent.

**init**.py

```
from . import controllers
from . import models
import threading
import skpy



class MySkype(skpy.SkypeEventLoop):
    def onEvent(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, skpy.SkypeNewMessageEvent):
            print(repr(event))
            message = ('New message from user {} at {}: \'{} \''.format(event.msg.userId,
                                                                        event.msg.time.strftime(
                                                                            '%H:%M dd. %d.%m.%Y'),
                                                                        event.msg.content))
            models.models.skype_bot.SentMail(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from skpy import Skype
    global client
    global sk
    client = Skype('', '', '.skype_token')
    sk = MySkype(tokenFile=".skype_token", autoAck=True)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=sk.loop)
    thread.start()
```

models.py

```
    from odoo import models, fields, api
import threading
import skpy
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class skype_bot(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'skype_bot'
    _name = 'my.skype'
    _description = 'My Skype'



    def SentMail(self, message):
        self.env['mail.message'].create({'message_type': "notification",
                                         "subtype": self.env.ref("mail.mt_comment").id,  # subject type
                                         'body': message,
                                         'subject': "Message subject",
                                         'needaction_partner_ids': [(4, 3, 1)],
                                         # partner to whom you send notification
                                         })


        self.message_post(
            subject='Skype message',
            body=message,
            partner_ids=[(4, 3, 1)]
        )

    SentMail("test")
```

You can see all code here https://github.com/Sabrjkee/odootry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use  _inherit = ['mail.thread'] in model